# Why isn't typename interchangeable with decltype() for this usage?

Tags: c++14, decltype, typename

For a given usage

```
template<typename T1> 
class node{

public:
using sp2node = shared_ptr<node<T1>>;
using r_sp2node = shared_ptr<node<T1>>&;

public:
r_sp2Node getN();

private:
sp2node N;

};
```

(1)

```
template<typename T1> decltype(node<T1>::r_sp2node) node<T1>::getN(){

       return N;

}
```

(2)

```
template<typename T1> typename node<T1>::r_sp2node node<T1>::getN(){

       return N;

}
```

(1) generates the compiler error:

```
error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 
    'node<T1>::r_sp2node'
```

whereas (2) compiles

Can someonene explain what is the difference between the above two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong with the first example.

- In `decltype(node<T1>::r_sp2node)`, reading inside out, the compiler first needs to know what `node<T1>::r_sp2node`. Is it a type, or something else? This is why the `typename` disambiguator exists, and that is what the error message is all about.
- The second problem is that `decltype` expects some expression, not a type. So even if you used `typename`, it still wouldn't compile. (As a simple example, `decltype(int)` won't even compile.)

To answer the question specifically, the difference between the two is that the first is not valid C++ and the second is the way to go.